# How retain Table permission on owner change at PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a use case that requires me to the change the owner of some tables
but when I change the owner it revokes all permissions.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable OWNER TO newOwner;
```

Now, when I try to see the permission all of them are gone:

```
SELECT grantee, privilege_type, table_name
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants
WHERE table_name=('myTable');
```

Is there a way to keep privileges on the alter table command ?

Comment: this is because owner does not need any permissions on its relation - just change owner back

Answer (score 0):

owner does not need explicit permission on own relation. either change owner back or run

```
GRANT ALL on myTable to oldOwner;
```

Comment: yes but i want other user that allready got "Granted" to be retain with their grant .